# Python: Multiple ways to initialize a class

Tags: python

I have a class `A` which can be 'initialized' in two different ways. So, I provide a 'factory-like' interface for it based on the second answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682504/what-is-a-clean-pythonic-way-to-have-multiple-constructors-in-python).

```
class A(object):

    @staticmethod
    def from_method_1(<method_1_parameters>):
        a = A()
        # set parameters of 'a' using <method_1_parameters>
        return a

    @staticmethod
    def from_method_2(<method_2_parameters>):
        a = A()
        # set parameters of 'a' using <method_2_parameters>
        return a
```

The two methods are different enough that I can't just plug their parameters into the class's `__init__`. So, class `A` should be initialized using:

```
a = A.from_method_1(<method_1_parameters>)
```

or

```
a = A.from_method_2(<method_2_parameters>)
```

However, it is still possible to call the 'default init' for `A`:

```
a = A() # just an empty 'A' object
```

Is there any way to prevent this? I can't just raise `NotImplementedError` from `__init__` because the two 'factory methods' use it too.

Or do I need to use a completely different approach altogether.

Comment: You can just provide a default action for `a = A()`, like always call `from_method_1()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Has been a very long time since this question was asked but I think it's interesting enough to be revived.

When I first saw your problem the [`private constructor`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2062560/10657880) concept just popped out my mind. It's a concept important in other OOP languages, but as Python doesn't enforces privacy I didn't really thought about it since Python became my main language.

Therefore, I became curious and I found this ["Private Constructor in Python" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212053/private-constructor-in-python). It covers pretty much all about this topic and I think the second answer can be helpful in here.

Basically it uses [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to declare a pseudo-private class attribute ([there isn't such thing as private variables in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)) and assign the class object to it. Therefore you'll have an as-private-as-Python allows variable to use to check if your initialization was made from an class method or from an outside call. I made the following example based on this mechanism:

```
class A(object):
    __obj = object()

    def __init__(self, obj=None):
        assert(obj == A.__obj), \
            'A object must be created using A.from_method_1 or A.from_method_2'

    @classmethod
    def from_method_1(cls):
        a = A(cls.__obj)
        print('Created from method 1!')
        return a

    @classmethod
    def from_method_2(cls):
        a = A(cls.__obj)
        print('Created from method 2!')
        return a
```

Tests:

```
>>> A()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "t.py", line 6, in __init__
    'A object must be created using A.from_method_1 or A.from_method_2'
AssertionError: A object must be created using A.from_method_1 or A.from_method_2
>>> A.from_method_1()
Created from method 1!
<t.A object at 0x7f3f7f2ca450>
>>> A.from_method_2()
Created from method 2!
<t.A object at 0x7f3f7f2ca350>
```

However, as this solution is a workaround with name mangling, it does have one flaw if you know how to look for it:

```
>>> A(A._A__obj)
<t.A object at 0x7f3f7f2ca450>
```