# What's the cleanest possible way to hint that a python function accepts two arguments but only one of them must be populated?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, type-hinting

```
class Authenticator:
    def __init__(api_key: str, user_pass: tuple[str, str]):
        raise NotImplemented
```

What' the cleanest way to write that Authenticator can be instantiated or via an api key or via a username-password tuple (but not both obviously)? I'd like to keep both parameters in the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will be more readable if you use two different methods instead of constructor method

```py
class Authenticator:

    def auth_by_key(api_key):
        pass

    def auth_by_u_p(u, p):
        pass
```

Comment: there's truth in this, but you're missing a crucial point - what does the `__init__` method look like, since you'll need one? One option is to use something like in an [answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68366676/5986907)

Comment: Agree, I like the solution @joel proposed better. Would you mind reporting it as answer to this question? I might do it myself, but it's yours, I don't want to steal it.

Comment: @chattershuts you're welcome to copy-paste if you want, but might this be a duplicate question if you want to do that?