# What is a pythonic way to create a factory method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, factory, factory-pattern

I have a class, and I would prefer that people call a factory method in order to create instance of the class instead of instantiating the class directly.

One of a few different reasons to use a factory method is so that we can use `functools.wrap` to wrap un-decorated callable.

```python
import inspect 

class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, kallable):
        self._kallable = kallable
        
    @classmethod
    def make_decorator(kls, kallable):
        wrapped_kallable = kls(kallable)
        return functools.wrap(wrapped_kallable, kallable)
        
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func_name = self._kallable.__name__ 
        func_name = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name
        
        print("ENTERING FUNCTION ", func_name)
        
        ret_val = self._kallable(*args, **kwargs)
        
        print("LEAVING FUNCTION", self._kallable)
        
        return ret_val
```

Printing `"ENTERING FUNCTION "` is kind of a silly thing to do, I wanted to show you a ***minimal*** reproducible example of what I am trying to do (create a decorator-class which uses `functools.wrap` and which is instantiated from a factory method)

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212053/private-constructor-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a factory method for the purpose of calling `functools.wraps` on the instance being created. Override the `__new__` method instead:

```
class Decorator:
    def __new__(cls, kallable):
        return functools.wraps(kallable)(super().__new__(cls))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/MediumpurpleBraveCleaninstall

Comment: Should `__new__` accept only the class as input, or should we also pass an instance of the class into `__new__`?  Do we write `super().__new__(cls, kallable)` or only `super().__new__(cls)`?